# Can't add ssh public keys on azure devops page

Tags: azure-devops

At below page,

Can't add ssh public keys on azure devops page and not sure why.

[image: 1]

After clicking on SSH Public Keys and pasting the keys and with propername and ADD, I can't see them as listed. Is that how is it represented?

Tried adding as mentioned in the link

Comment: After you entered the Name and Public Key Data on the "Add New SSH Key" page, did you click the "Add" button in the lower right corner of the page? If you click, what happens afterward? If the SSH key is added successfully, you can see the key you added on the page shown in your screenshot. According to your screenshot, your SSH key has not been added successfully. For detailed info about adding SSH key, you can refer to [Use SSH key authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Yes, after pasting the ssh keys and giving a name, I clicked on the Add button(the one on lower right corner) but still didn't added as I can't see any list ssh keys or any message or warning saying as successfully added.

Comment: To narrow down the issue, you can check if other users in your organization have the same issue and if there is the same issue in other organization for your account. At the same time, you can press F12 or open the Developer tools of the browser to check the network traces when adding SSH key. You can see in the network trace whether DevOps has a request to add an SSH key. If so, you can continue to check whether there are other requests that cause the addition to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after pasting the ssh keys and giving a name, I clicked on the Add button(the one on lower right corner) but still didn't added as I can't see any list ssh keys or any message or warning saying as successfully added.

[SshKeyImagenAdd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8fLB.png)

[SshKeyImagenAdd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzSQx.png)